# How to keep SwiftUI from creating additional StateObjects in this custom page view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

## Abstract

I'm creating an app that allows for content creation and display. The UX I yearn for requires the content creation view to use programmatic navigation. I aim at architecture with a main view model and an additional one for the content creation view. **The problem is, the content creation view model does not work as I expected in this specific example.**

---

### Code structure

*Please note that this is a minimal reproducible example.*

Suppose there is a `ContentView: View` with a nested `AddContentPresenterView: View`. The nested view consists of two phases:

- specifying object's name
- summary screen

To allow for programmatic navigation with `NavigationStack` *(new in iOS 16)*, each phase has an associated value.

Assume that `AddContentPresenterView` requires the view model. No workarounds with `@State` will do - I desire to learn how to handle `ObservableObject` in this case.

### Code

#### ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ContentViewViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationStack(path: $model.path) {
                List(model.content) { element in
                    Text(element.name)
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Content.self) { element in
                    ContentDetailView(content: element)
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Page.self) { page in
                    AddContentPresenterView(page: page)
                }
            }
            Button {
                model.navigateToNextPartOfContentCreation()
            } label: {
                Label("Add content", systemImage: "plus")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

#### ContentDetailView (irrelevant)

```
struct ContentDetailView: View {
    let content: Content
    var body: some View {
        Text(content.name)
    }
}
```

#### AddContentPresenterView

As `navigationDestination` *associates a destination view with a presented data type for use within a navigation stack*, I found no better way of adding a paged view to be navigated using the `NavigationStack` than this.

```
extension AddContentPresenterView {
    var contentName: some View {
        TextField("Name your content", text: $addContentViewModel.contentName)
            .onSubmit {
                model.navigateToNextPartOfContentCreation()
            }
    }
    var contentSummary: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(addContentViewModel.contentName)
            Button {
                model.addContent(addContentViewModel.createContent())
                model.navigateToRoot()
            } label: {
                Label("Add this content", systemImage: "checkmark.circle")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### ContentViewViewModel

Controls the navigation and adding content.

```
class ContentViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    @Published var content: [Content] = []
    
    func navigateToNextPartOfContentCreation() {
        switch path.count {
        case 0:
            path.append(Page.contentName)
        case 1:
            path.append(Page.contentSummary)
        default:
            fatalError("Navigation error.")
        }
    }
    
    func navigateToRoot() {
        path.removeLast(path.count)
    }
    
    func addContent(_ content: Content) {
        self.content.append(content)
    }
}
```

#### AddContentViewModel

Manages content creation.

```
class AddContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var contentName = ""
    
    func createContent() -> Content {
        return Content(name: contentName)
    }
}
```

#### Page

Enum containing creation screen pages.

```
enum Page: Hashable {
    case contentName, contentSummary
}
```

---

### What is wrong

Currently, for each page pushed onto the navigation stack, a new `StateObject` is created. That makes the creation of object impossible, since the `addContentViewModel.contentName` holds value only for the bound screen.

I thought that, since `StateObject` is tied to the view's lifecycle, it's tied to `AddContentPresenterView` and, therefore, I would be able to share it.

### What I've tried

The error is resolved when `addContentViewModel` in `AddContentPresenterView` is an `EnvironmentObject` initialized in `App` itself. Then, however, it's tied to the `App`'s lifecycle and subsequent content creations greet us with stale data - *as it should be*.

### Wraping up

**How to keep SwiftUI from creating additional StateObjects in this custom page view?**

Should I resort to `ObservedObject` and try some wizardry? Should I just implement a `reset` method for my `AddContentViewModel` and reset the data on entering or quiting the screen?

Or maybe there is a better way of achieving what I've summarized in abstract?

Comment: If you add `@StateObject var addContentViewModel = AddContentViewModel()` in your `AddContentPresenterView` it will always initialise new ViewModel object when you add `AddContentPresenterView`in navigation stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare `@StateObject var addContentViewModel = AddContentViewModel()` in your `AddContentPresenterView` it will always initialise new `AddContentViewModel` object when you add `AddContentPresenterView` in navigation stack. Now looking at your code and app flow I don't fill you need `AddContentViewModel`.

---

First, update your `contentSummary` of the `Page` enum with an associated value like this.

```
enum Page {
    case contentName, contentSummary(String)
}
```

Now update your navigate to the next page method of your `ContentViewModel` like below.

```
func navigateToNextPage(_ page: Page) {
    path.append(page)
}
```

Now for `ContentView`, I think you need to add `VStack` inside `NavigationStack` otherwise that bottom plus button will always be visible.

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ContentViewViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $model.path) {
            VStack {
                List(model.content) { element in
                    Text(element.name)
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Content.self) { element in
                    ContentDetailView(content: element)
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Page.self) { page in
                    switch page {
                    case .contentName: AddContentView()
                    case .contentSummary(let name): ContentSummaryView(contentName: name)
                    }
                }
                Button {
                    model.navigateToNextPage(.contentName)
                } label: {
                    Label("Add content", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

So now it will push destination view on basis of the type of the `Page`. So you can remove your `AddContentPresenterView` and add `AddContentView` and `ContentSummaryView`.

**AddContentView**

```
struct AddContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ContentViewViewModel
    @State private var contentName = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Name your content", text: $contentName)
            .onSubmit {
                model.navigateToNextPage(.contentSummary(contentName))
            }
    }
}
```

**ContentSummaryView**

```
struct ContentSummaryView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ContentViewViewModel
    let contentName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(contentName)
            Button {
                model.addContent(Content(name: contentName))
                model.navigateToRoot()
            } label: {
                Label("Add this content", systemImage: "checkmark.circle")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see I have used `@State` property in AddContentView to bind it with `TextField` and on submit I'm passing it as an associated value with `contentSummary`. So this will reduce the use of `AddContentViewModel`. So now there is no need to reset anything or you want face any issue of data loss when you push to ContentSummaryView.

Comment: Although your solution would work in this specific example, I do need the `AddContentViewModel` in my actual project, as there are a few stages of content creating. This is just a minimal reproducible example, which I've failed to emphasize.

Comment: Also, I would consider adding navigation logic into the `ContentView` is a bad practice. It belongs to the `ContentViewViewModel`.

Comment: In my answer navigation is still triggering with `ContentViewViewModel`, I just changed your method. Also if you want `AddContentViewModel` you can go with that but as I already said every time you load your `AddContentView` it will create new object, to overcome this issue you can add a separate ViewModel for ContentSummaryView and pass required details via associated value. Let me know if more details needed will update my answer with this suggestion

Comment: I've read some more about app architecture, implemented your solution and I must admit - yes, I did not need this `StateObject` there.

Comment: @JordanNiedzielski Happy help mate :)